# How to convert from asp.net forms authentication to windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I've been asked to convert an asp.net application from forms authentication with roles using the aspnetdb database to use windows authentication instead.

what is required to do this?  can I still use the roles defined in the app and stored in aspnetdb?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can use Windows Authentication for the membership provider, and SqlRoleManager for the role provider. So you end up with Windows Authentication telling your app what user is accessing the page, and you can setup your own application-specific roles in your database for those Windows Auth users -- which is distinct and separate from whatever roles they have in Active Directory.

[ScottGu has a detailed explanation here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx).
[image: ScottGU article]

Comment: that article doesn't say to convert an existing app with roles